# ¿Como imprimir todos los numeros divisibles de un numero ingresado por teclado? Java For

Tags: java, bucle-for, condiciones

Holaa buenas , estoy haciendo un programa donde debo realizar la division de dos numeros y si da 0 evaluar si el primer numero es divisible por el divisor , de ser asi imprimir todos los numeros divisible del divisor.
Hasta el momento hice para numeros pares e impares , pero solo funciona si ingreso el 2 o el 3 , que pasa si yo quiero ingresar un 7 o un 8 , no me sale sus divisores , como podria hacer eso? , es decir , quiero ingresar cualquier numero y que me de sus primeros 10 numeros divisibles .Espero que haber sido claro . Ahora les dejo lo que hice :

```
public class Divisibles {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
     int numero1 =0;
     int numero2 = 0;
     int par = 0;
     int impar = 0;
     int suma1=0;
     int suma2=0;
     System.out.println("Ingrese numero : ");
     numero1 = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese otro :");
    numero2 = teclado.nextInt();

     for(int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++) {

         if(numero1%numero2==0) {

            if(numero2%2==0) {

                par+=2; //tuve que realizar esto por que sino no 
                        //salian numeros como el 16 o 18.
                suma1=par;

                System.out.println(suma1);

            }

            else if(numero2%3==0) { 


                impar+=3; //lo mismo aca le sume 3 por que no 
                          //salian numeros como el 9
                suma2=impar;

                System.out.println(suma2);
            }




         }




     }


}
```

}

Bueno se que este programa va a funcionar solo para numeros divisibles por 2 o 3 , asi que si tienen alguna idea de lo que le podria cambiar , gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este código te obtiene hasta diez factores de un número dado si éste los tuviera.

Lo que hace es buscar el *resto* ([modulo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operaci%C3%B3n_m%C3%B3dulo)) de la división entre el número dado y todos los números a partir de `1`. Si el *modulo* es igual a cero (no sobra nada en la división), significa que el número es divisible entre `i`.

El bucle tiene un `if` interior para detenerlo cuando `totalFactors` llegue a diez, para cumplir tu requerimiento de que no obtenga más de 10 factores.

```
    int totalFactors=0;
    int theNumber=96;
    for(int i = 1; i <= theNumber; ++i) {
        /*Verificamos si no sobra nada en la división*/
        if (theNumber % i == 0) {
            totalFactors++;
            System.out.printf("%02d. %d\n" , totalFactors,i);
            /*Detenemos el bucle cuando haya 10 factores*/
            if (totalFactors==10){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Salida:**

Los primeros diez factores de `96`, usado como número de prueba serían:

```
01. 1
02. 2
03. 3
04. 4
05. 6
06. 8
07. 12
08. 16
09. 24
10. 32
```

---

#### Código de prueba

<kbd>[**`VER DEMO EN REXTESTER`**](https://rextester.com/OPCE88638)</kbd>